# How to write a JUnit test for Base64.decodeBase64

Tags: java, junit

Below is my method for which i want to write Junit test case:

```
public static byte[] getDecodeBase64(JSONObject object,String key) {
        
  return Base64.decodeBase64(object.getString(key));
}
```

I wrote this:

```
@Test
    public void testGetDecodeBase64(){
        
        JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
        test.put("clientId", "test");
        
        String value = "[B@[2807bdeb]";
        
        assertEquals(value, JSONUtil.getDecodeBase64(test, "clientId").toString());
        
    }
```

But each time the value returned by the method is different.

Answer (score 1):

toString method of an array returns a string representing the Id of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `assertArrayEquals` to check what's in the array.

Or, if you want to test with String, to convert your byte array into a String with :

```
byte[] bytes = {...}
String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: i am getting this error: org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[[B@[2807bdeb]]> but was:<[��-]> for this code:

@Test
 public void testGetDecodeBase64() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
  
  JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
  test.put("clientId", "test");
  
  String value = "[B@[2807bdeb]";
  
  //assertEquals(value, JSONUtil.getDecodeBase64(test, "clientId").toString());
  
  byte[] bytes = JSONUtil.getDecodeBase64(test, "clientId");
  String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
  assertEquals(value, str);
  
 }